# Is there any way to open TCPDF output in a new tab/window without using HTML tag("target=_blank")?

Tags: tcpdf

I have a question, I'm using TCPDF to generate report in pdf format using php, and I'm struggling to open the TCPDF output in new tab but unable to achieve it. Can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.
I've tried with the php code for TCPDF output.

```
<pre>require_once('library/tcpdf.php');
$obj_pdf = new TCPDF('L', PDF_UNIT, 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
$obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$obj_pdf->SetTitle("Vehicle Report");     
$obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
$obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');  
$obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
$obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);  
$obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);
$obj_pdf->AddPage();

<pre>$obj_pdf->setFont('freesans', '',9);
$obj_pdf->writeHTML($content , true, false, true, false, '');
ob_end_clean();
$obj_pdf->output('pdfReport.pdf', 'I', '_blank');
window.open('pdfReport.pdf', '_blank');
```

Comment: what's wrong with the target?

Comment: actually, I'm using this TCPDF in a form which has more than 1 submit button, so if I use "target=_blank" then the other submit buttons also opening in new tab. This is the very reason I've asked for other way around.